# Can AudioKit extract EQed samples asynchronously without AVAudioEngine?

Tags: ios, audiokit, avaudioengine

I need to extract waveform data asynchronously from a file after having applied some equalization. Using the AVAudioEngine [I encounter in random silences](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/111249) at the beginning of the samples (it's more of a delay of the real data but unfortunately such delay can't be detected for instance with a longer number of samples).

[image]

I asked directly to Apple using the code support tickets but they don't have a solution. Looks like AVAudioEngine offline rendering mode is bugged.

Looking for third party solutions, I came across AudioKit which seems to be using AVAudioEngine. So, assuming AudioKit can extract asynchronously a waveform after EQ is applied, would it do it bypassing AVAudioEngine offline mode?

Comment: Maybe I am in luck and it uses the lower level audio unit: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/d3da07d24b43ce23fbb7a5bafbf43db4104e8211/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Offline/OfflineRender/AKOfflineRenderNode.swift

Comment: Looks like [it does](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/d3da07d24b43ce23fbb7a5bafbf43db4104e8211/AudioKit/Common/Internals/AVAudioEngine%2BExtensions.swift) but only for rendering to file, what about extracting samples data?

Comment: No one else can see the bug report you linked to. Can you copy it here, and say more about what you’re trying to do?

Comment: @AaronBrager ops, re-edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: 185MB .framework is definitely overkill for what I need.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would include the code in your question.